# Android - Access Google Drive Offline files via File Manager

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am on Android 4.4.3 with Google Drive app.
I need to access the Google Drive files marked as "Keep on this device" via "File Manager" app.

Can someone guide me the location in the File Manager where I can locate these offline files?

Answer (score -1):

In Android 4.4.3 & Google Drive Version 1.3.144.25, the Google Drive files marked as "Keep on this device" can be accessed at the below location via File Manager

```
com.google.android.apps.docs/files/pinned_docs_files_do_not_edit/ # continues below
{long_random_alphanumeric_folder_name}/{your_file}
```

As the one of the folder name suggests "do_not_edit", I would refrain from doing so. But I just want to read the file so I am hoping that I am good. Further to note, the files are in encrypted format so you will not be able to do much by accessing these files via File Manager.